# AWS ElasticSearch - Automating manual snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, snapshot, retention

**The requirement** - A customer requires an automated mechanism that takes a [manual snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-create) of an AWS ElasticSearch domain (production) on a daily basis. The target of the snapshot is an AWS S3 bucket.

**Expected flow**

1. Schedule Daily @ 2am --> start process --> take snapshot --> wait 5 min --> check snapshot status (success/in_progress/failed)
2. if `state==IN_PROGRESS`, check snapshot status again, up to 10 times, interval of 5 mins

   - `state==SUCCESS` - end process (success)
   - `state==IN_PROGRESS` - when reaching 10 retries (50 mins), end process (failed)
   - `state==FAILED` - end process (failed)
3. If previous step failed, send push notification (Slack/Teams/Email/etc.)

**Motivation** - The automated snapshots that are taken by AWS can be used for disaster recovery or a failure in an upgrade, they cannot be used if someone by accident (yes, it happened) deleted the whole ElasticSearch cluster.

Haven't found an out-of-the-box Lambda/mechanism that meets the requirements. Suggestions? Thoughts?

p.s- I did a POC with AWS Step Functions + Lambda in VPC, which seems to be working, but I'd rather use a managed service or a living open-source project.

Comment: What about using https://cloud.elastic.co? It has automatic backups, runs on AWS (and others) and is the official service supported by the makers of Elastic Stack. You can also get it from https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Elastic-Elastic-Cloud-Elasticsearch-managed-servic/B01N6YCISK

Comment: Sounds interesting, but it means I'll need to migrate the current ElasticSearch instance to this solution, not something that I'm inclined to do :\ I need something that works with my current setup

Comment: Not sure it helps, but there's a guide here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-from-aws.html

Comment: Thank you dadoonet, i ended up creating a pipeline that automatically does it with AWS Step Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you accidentally delete your AWS Elasticsearch domain, AWS Support can help you recover the domain along with its latest snapshot ***on best effort basis***. This is not listed in the documentation since this shouldn't ideally be your first bet.

Assuming this will be rare scenario, you should be fine. However, if you think there are fair chances of your AWS ES cluster getting delete again and again, you will be better off setting up a lambda function to save a latest snapshot in your own S3 bucket. This will save you from depending on AWS support as well.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elasticsearch have accidental delete protection. Incase you delete your domain by mistake, AWS elasticsearch can recover it within 14 days.
Hope this solves your purpose.

Comment: Could you please share a link? I haven't found it

Comment: I recommend to talk to AWS customer support regarding this.